# load 2 modules when launching powershell from cmd?

Tags: powershell, cmd

I want to have a one liner that launches powershell and imports two modules.
To load one module this line works:

```
powershell -command import-module 'c:\module1'
```

But how to load two modules? or - how to run two commands when opening power shell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Import-Module](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=141553) cmdlet takes a string array, so you can comma separate your modules to import (which will **implicit** creates a string array):

```
powershell -command import-module 'c:\module1', 'c:\module2'
```

Alternative, you can **explicit** create a string array and pass it to the `Import-Module` cmdlet:

```
powershell -command import-module @('c:\module1', 'c:\module2')
```

For your second question, I suggest you to read [about_Profiles](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847857.aspx).

Comment: Your welcome. For you second question (how to run commands when opening powershell), you should read about_Profiles (see my edited answer).